# custom validation about unique of more than one field in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unique

I have a table `tanks`

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| id | capacity | model | width |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1000 |    15 |   960 |
|  2 |    50000 |    30 |   200 |
|  3 |      100 |    15 |    12 |
|  4 |    80000 |    40 |   100 |
|  5 |     1000 |    30 |   123 |
|  6 |      500 |     5 |  1213 |
|  7 |     1000 |    22 |  2234 |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

And I added the unique property in my table

```
ALTER TABLE `tanks`
ADD UNIQUE `capacity_model_width` (`capacity`, `model`, `width`);
```

And my function to store values is like this

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $image = new tank();

        $this->validate($request, [
                'capacity' => 'required|numeric',
                'model' => 'required|numeric',
                'width' => 'required|numeric',
            ]                
                );

        $image->capacity = $request->capacity;
        $image->model = $request->model;
        $image->width = $request->width;
        $image->save();

        return redirect()->route('tank.index')
                        ->with('success', 'Tank created successfully');
    }
```

Now when I insert below error shows

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'1000-22-2234' for key 'capacity_model_width'
```

I need to show the error message in  my submit if they are unique. I am new to Laravel, How can add a custom validation and error message inside the store function

Comment: So are you concatenating the model width and capacity for the key?

Comment: There's a validatio rule [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique).

Comment: @ChrisTownsend no concatenation for them

Comment: @AhmadRezk I know but it is not for two or more fields it doesn't works for me

Comment: So how did your key turn into '1000-22-2234' ?

Comment: @ChrisTownsend I dont know but laravel shows that error when I check

Comment: Forget the schema I see it. I can see what you are doing now. You need to check to see if the combined fields are unique? is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code

We are going to check to see if the fields we need exist first then we will concatenate them and add them to the request. From there we can now run our unique validation

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $image = new tank();
    //Check to see if fields exist then validate after concatenation

    if(isset($request->capacity) && isset($request->model) && isset($request->width) ){
         $request->request->add(['my_key' => ['capacity' => $request->capacity, 'model' => $request->model, 'width' => $request->width] ]);
    }
    $this->validate($request, [
            'capacity' => 'required|numeric',
            'model' => 'required|numeric',
            'width' => 'required|numeric',
            'my_key' => 'required|uniqueCapacity',
        ]                
            );

    $image->capacity = $request->capacity;
    $image->model = $request->model;
    $image->width = $request->width;
    $image->save();

    return redirect()->route('tank.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Tank created successfully');
}
```

Adding a custom validator

Firstly access your AppServiceProvider and add the following

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('uniqueCapacity', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
       $value_array = explode("-", $value);
        $items = DB::select("SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM tanks WHERE capacity ='$value_array[0]' AND model='$value_array[1]' AND width='$value_array[2]' "); 
        $number=$items[0]->aggregate;
        if ($number > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is that you could automatically concatenate the fields in JavaScript in a hidden field. This can then be passed through the request

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'capacity_model_width' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tanks` where `capacity_model_width` = 1000-22-2234)

Comment: Okay so that column doesn't actually exist in the table? It's just a rule?

Comment: Okay that sounds like we would need a custom validator. I haven't done one before but you can try what I'm about to put

Comment: Thanks Chris For your effort.

Comment: Have a look, again this is a first time doing this and I'm not sure about the error messages, but change the bit where we are adding the request to an array and add the new validor to the appservice provider

Comment: OK let me check it

Comment: Sorry another change, Needed to reverse the output, so that if one exists the validator returns false

Comment: Thanks it works with little bit modification on my own

Comment: Great, if there were no errors with my way can you mark it as an answer please

Comment: $value_array = explode("-", $value);
        $items = DB::select("SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM tanks WHERE capacity ='$value_array[0]' AND model='$value_array[1]' AND width='$value_array[2]' "); 
        $number=$items[0]->aggregate;

Comment: if ($number > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

Comment: Can you change the answer like this

Answer (score 0):

### Simple change in validation

```
this->validate($request, [
                'capacity' => 'required|email|unique:table_name',
                'model' => 'required|email|unique:table_name',
                'width' => 'required|email|unique:table_name',
            ]
```

Comment: Its for each one  I need Three fields together

Answer (score 0):

Add unique validation rule to capacity to be like that

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'capacity' => 'required|numeric|unique:tanks,capacity',
            'model' => 'required|numeric',
            'width' => 'required|numeric',
        ]                
            );
```

And you can Adding Additional Where Clauses

```
 Validator::make($request, [
'capacity' => Rule::unique('tanks')->where(function ($query) use $request {
$query->where('capacity', $request->input('capacity'))->where('width', $request->input('width'))->where('model', $request->input('model'));
})
]);
```

[laravel unique doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: Its for capacity only I need Three fields together